# How to compare two lookup field in system.AssertEquals

Tags: apex, trigger, unit-test

I have an object Timecard *( pse__Timecard_Header__c )* inside which there is a field called **Period__c**. I have another object Period *(c2g__codaPeriod__c).*

In system.assertEquals I want to compare these two things the field **(Period__c)** from Timecard and **ID** of period

```
 pse__Timecard_Header__c th1 = new pse__Timecard_Header__c(
            CurrencyIsoCode         = 'USD',
            pse__Project__c         = project.ID,
            pse__Resource__c        = pmResource.Id,
            pse__Monday_Hours__c    = 8,
            pse__Tuesday_Hours__c   = 8,
            pse__Wednesday_Hours__c = 8,
            pse__Thursday_Hours__c  = 8,
            pse__Friday_Hours__c    = 8,
            pse__Start_Date__c      = Date.today().toStartOfWeek(),
            pse__End_Date__c        = Date.today().toStartOfWeek()+6
        );
  insert th1;


         System.runAs(pmUser) {
        delete th1;
        system.assert([select ID from pse__Timecard_Header__c WHERE Id = :th1.Id ].IsEmpty());
                              }
        system.assertEquals(th1.Period__c, c2g__codaPeriod__c.Id);
```

This is giving me error **Comparison arguments must be compatible types: Id, Schema.SObjectField**. Also I would like to know whether I can use *system.assert* and *system.assertEquals* both.

Answer (score 1):

`c2g__codaPeriod__c.Id` refers to `Schema.c2g__codaPeriod__c.Id`, which is a field reference; you'll want to have a Period record and get its specific ID value. You'll need to crate a period record prior to running the test, unless the trigger creates the record as part of the process.